# Moment.js depreciation - how to find line of code causing waring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, warnings, momentjs

I am trying to debug an application I did not write myself. The last issue is the moment.js depreciation error: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

I understand how to format the date correctly to resolove the issue, but its a fairly complicated calendar booking system. moment.js is heavily used throughout.

**Is there a better way to use debugging tools or console log to determine what file / line is throwing the warning message. Rather than read throught all the code line by line?**

thank you

Comment: could set breakpoints at various stages and at least narrow down sections of code

Comment: Maybe you're referring to `printMsg` for deprecation warnings around line ~305?  Just control-f for "deprecation warning" and comment out the `console.warn` if you want to hide the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully placed "debugger" inside the calling warning function of moment to trigger chrome debug tool and pause the application when an warning occurred. 
Then used sources > Stack, inside the debugger, to point out where the warnings are getting called from.